# GNU Parallel: How to limit max running network jobs per host

Tags: limit, gnu-parallel

I'm using GNU Parallel for scanning a list of urls (from different hosts) for vulnerability, like this:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel --gnu -j 50 ./scan {}
```

The 'scan' program works for one url in one thread. And I need to hard-limit the number of simultaneous requests (jobs) to each host, for example to 5 connections. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you want 5 jobs to each host or 5 urls to be processed at a time?

Comment: I want total 50 urls to be processed at a time and 5 or less jobs to each host. (to not overload that servers)

Answer (score 1):

Split urls into one file per host. Then run 'parallel -j5' on each file.

Or sort urls and insert a delimiter '\0' when a new host is met, then split on '\0' and remove '\0' while passing that as a block to a new instance of parallel:

```
sort urls.txt | 
  perl -pe '(not m://$last:) and print "\0";m://([^/]+): and $last=$1' |
  parallel -j10 --pipe --rrs -N1 --recend '\0' parallel -j5 ./scan
```

Edit:

I think this will work:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel -q -j50 sem --fg --id '{= m://([^/]+):; $_=$1 =}' -j5 ./scan {}
```

`sem` is part of GNU Parallel (it is a shorthand for `parallel --semaphore`). `{= m://([^/]+):; $_=$1 =}` grabs the hostname. `-j5` tells `sem` to make a counting semaphore with 5 slots. `--fg` forces `sem` to not spawn the job in the background. By using the hostname as ID you will get a counting semaphore for each hostname.

`-q` is needed for `parallel` if some of your URLs contain special shell chars (such as &). They need to be protected from shell expansion because `sem` will also shell expand them.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.
But in my input file there are lots of hosts having 4 or less links.
And also in your solution, each of the 'parallel -j5' will run as long as the slowest scan of these 5. Maybe there is a way to make a total number of running jobs equal to 50?